# what is vextern used for in this code?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have some c code that uses vextern as shown below and would like to know what the purpose of this is:

file1.c:

```
#define FILE1_G_
```

file1.h:

```
#ifdef FILE1_G_
# define vextern
#else
# define vextern extern
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess that `define` is used to define variables only in one file, but declare them in all files that include this header.

If in `file1.h`, you have `vextern int a;`, and you include this file in some .c files, the variable `a` will be defined only in the file that has the line `#define FILE1_G_`. (In your example, `file1.c`)

Comment: I'm not sure which one is correct.  The other answer suggests that only the word vextern will be affected.  So that would mean that int a would always be defined?

Comment: It will not be defined. It will be declared. (When you write a program with some files, you have to define a variable only once, but you should declare it in every file that uses it.)

Answer (score 2):

It's a [preprocessor macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion).

If `FILE1_G_` is defined then all occurances of `vextern` are replaced with `extern`. If not, then they're removed (replaced with nothing)

**Edit to clarify based on comments below:**

It means it's either declared as `extern` or not; only the word `vextern` is affected.

As for the use case ... it allows a `.c` file to define the things "tagged" by `vextern` by defining `FILE1_G_` before including that header.

The default (`FILE1_G_` wasn't defined) means that the `.c` file that is currently including `file1.h` didn't define `FILE1_G_` and is not defining things that were tagged with `vextern`, but can use them because they've been declared in that header and defined somewhere else.

Comment: So in the case of having the .h file stating:  vextern void func(int x);  This would basically either be defined as an extern void func(int x);  or void func(int x).  Either way since the default is extern this would deem unnecessary in this situation correct?  Or does it mean the entire line is replaced with nothing?

Comment: I cleaned up my reply comment and posted it as an edit to my answer.